# How to define an auto height into a var

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to put my footer under the section div, the section's height is auto so i can't define a top.

I'm trying to define the height using this script:

```
function footer()
{
  var h = parseFloat(document.getElementById("sect").style.height);
  document.getElementById("foot").style.top = h + "px";
}
```

It doesn't work because it doesn't read the height as the number but as the string 'auto'.
Is possible to do it? There is a better way to do it?

Comment: Using JS as a crutch for the UI is a really bad idea. I would suggest you do something like add some padding/margin to the bottom of the section which matches the height of the footer, then position the footer absolutely to `bottom: 0`. If you could show the HTML and CSS we can give you a working example of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly as you want to find the height of your element in javascript then here are your options:

```
const elm = document.getElementById("sect");

// Returns an object with left, x, top, y, right, bottom, width, height properties of the element.
// width and height includes the border and padding. Others are relative to the top/left of the viewport
elm.getBoundingClientRect();

 // Viewable width/height of the element including padding, but NOT border, scrollbar or margin (excludes overflow)
elm.clientWidth;
elm.clientHeight;

// Viewable width/height of the element including padding, border, scrollbar, but NOT margin (excludes overflow)
elm.offsetWidth;
elm.offsetHeight;

// Entire width/height of the element including padding, but NOT border, scrollbar or margin (includes overflow)
elm.scrollWidth;
elm.scrollHeight;
```

so your function may looks like:

```
function footer()
{
  var h = parseFloat(document.getElementById("sect").offsetHeight);
  document.getElementById("foot").style.top = h + "px";
}
```